# Google sheets get first occurrence from duplicate column headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I need to get the first occurrence from duplicate column headers as follows:

[image]

A workaround was to group all the same columns and use an `IF` blank then get next column formula. However, it seems not efficient if a column was added in between or the columns were re-arranged in some way. So the quickest way I could think of is to just get the first occurrence from a range that's equal to the column header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first column:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A1:E5, A1:E1="name"),,1)
```

first non empty:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(A1:E5, A1:E1="name")),,9^9))), " ")),,1)
```

whole table:

```
={INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:E5, A1:E1="name")),,9^9))), " ")),,1), B1:B5, 
  INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:E5, A1:E1="email")),,9^9))), " ")),,1)}
```

[image]

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(a, h, x, {
 INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(a, h="name")),,9^9))), " ")),,1), x, 
 INDEX(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(a, h="email")),,9^9))), " ")),,1)})
 (SUBSTITUTE(A1:E10, " ", CHAR(9)), A1:E1, B1:B10))
```

[image]

Comment: This is close already. It is just not getting the non-empty first occurrence. When using the whole table formula, the 2nd row's Name is empty as it should the "First" as the name. And for the 3rd row, it is not getting the email which should be "iron@man.com"

Comment: Oh I see you made an edit.. thank you for the updated answer. It is not getting the first non-empty however, can't seem to get other columns such as Country and Email

Comment: thank you so much! This totally answered my question

Comment: When using the first non-empty formula, it seems to be trimming by space. For instance, when I use the formula for the country column (`A1:E1="country"`) it returns "United" instead of "United States"

Answer (score 1):

I see you already accepted an answer, but just in case you or anyone needs this with more columns, you could use this formula:

```
=query({A1:Z},"Select Col"&JOIN(", Col",byrow(filter(unique(transpose(A1:1)),unique(transpose(A1:1))<>""),lambda(each,match(each,A1:1,0)))),true)
```

This will find first appearance of all unique headers and make the query ;)

[image]

Comment: I like how this is flexible to detect duplicate columns without specifying each columns. However, I am getting an error of "Circular dependency detected.".

Comment: Ohhh, you just have to limit the rows A:Z to your actual range (for example A1:Z10) that not overlaps the resulting table range ;)

Comment: That works now, thank you :) However, it is not getting the first non-empty value. Say for instance, on A3 I delete Doe, it will return blank which the expected result should be "sdff".

Comment: Ohhh, you're right, I was just looking for first appearance, not non-empty (I'll tell you later if I find a solution)